# "Cannot read property 'value' of null" Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, arcgis-js-api

I have got this error" Cannot read property 'value' of null" and not sure whats wrong with my code? I have some inputs in my popup that users can edit them, and I want to save edits.

```
view.popup.on("trigger-action", function(event) {
if (event.action.id === "edit") {

setupEditing(searchResults[arraypos]);
console.log(this);
}
if (event.action.id === "update") {

editFeature.attributes["common_name"] = document.getElementById('commonName').value;
editFeature.attributes["scientificname"] = document.getElementById('sientificName').value;
editFeature.attributes["family"] = document.getElementById('family').value;

var edits = {
updateFeatures: [editFeature]
};
console.log(editFeature.attributes);
tree.applyEdits({updates:[edits]}).then(response => console.log(response));
}
});
}
```

and here are my ids that seems correct:

```
function setupEditing(sr) {
     esripopupcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('esri-popup__content')[0];
   esripopupcontent.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>Common Name</td><td><input value=" + commonname + " id= commonName/></td></tr><tr><td>Scientific Name</td><td><input value=" + scientificname + " id= sientificName /></td></tr><tr><td>family</td><td><input value="+ family + " id= family/></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: One of your element ids is not on the page, or misspelled...the ".value" call is being called on null ... ie, it can't find the object by id...."document.getElementById('sientificName').value"?

Comment: 1. Please list the full, exact error message.
2. Provide your HTML

Comment: One of elements you have tried to "getById" does not exist. Without additional information I will not be able to tell you which one, but your browser console should tell you that.

Comment: This is the full error:  test55.html:309 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (test55.html:309)
    at Function.g.emit (init.js:53)
    at Object.emit (init.js:685)
    at Object.<anonymous> (MapView.js:149)
    at Object.l [as ontrigger-action] (init.js:63)
    at Function.g.emit (init.js:51)
    at Function.g.emit (init.js:53)
    at Object.emit (init.js:62)
    at Object.e (init.js:216)
    at Object.emit (init.js:374)